# Binding a nested collection in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding

I have a ViewModel which contains a list of polymorphic objects.

```
public class InputParameters
{
    public InputParameters()
    {
        InputPrompts = new List<IInputPrompt>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public IList<IInputPrompt> InputPrompts { get; set; }
}
```

Which in turn look this:

```
public interface IInputPrompt
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    bool IsHidden { get; set; }
    bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    dynamic Value { get; set; }
}
public class TextPrompt : IInputPrompt
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
}
public class MultiSelectPrompt : IInputPrompt
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }

    public MultiSelectList Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new MultiSelectList(((IDictionary<int, string>)Value).ToList(), "Key", "Value");
        }
    }
}
```

There is a Editor View Template for each of the derived types, the views look this this:

```
@model OptionListModelBinding.Models.InputParameters
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>@Model.Name</strong></legend>
        <div><em>@Model.Path</em></div>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(p => p.InputPrompts)</div>
        <div><input type="submit" /></div>
    </fieldset>

}
// editor template
@model OptionListModelBinding.Models.InputParameters
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>@Model.Name</strong></legend>
        <div><em>@Model.Path</em></div>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(p => p.InputPrompts)</div>
        <div><input type="submit" /></div>
    </fieldset>

} 
// editor template
@model OptionListModelBinding.Models.MultiSelectPrompt
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MultiSelectPrompt";
}

<h2>MultiSelectPrompt</h2>
<div><strong>@Model.Name</strong></div>
<div><em>@Html.ListBox(Model.Name, Model.Values)</em></div>
```

This all renders nicely:[image: Screen Capture]

The question is this:

How do I bind this back to the model?  I have a custom model binder: (excuse the hacked up nature of this code).

```
    public class InputParameterModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        }
        // iterate over the form fields
        foreach (string item in controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            // this is where the problem is ... I cannot use the generic here.
            var dog = FromPostedData<string>(bindingContext, item);

        }

        InputParameters userInput = new InputParameters();

        return userInput;
    }

    // Dino Esposito code
    private T FromPostedData<T>(ModelBindingContext context, string id)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) return default(T);
        var key = String.Format("{0}.{1}", context.ModelName, id);
        var result = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        if (result == null && context.FallbackToEmptyPrefix)
        {
            result = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(id);
            if (result == null) return default(T);
        }

        context.ModelState.SetModelValue(id, result);

        T valueToReturn = default(T);
        try
        {
            valueToReturn = (T)result.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
        }
        catch { }
        return valueToReturn;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Did i mention that the items in the list are determined at runtime?

**EDIT**
This is the front end of a report generating tool.  The backend service provides a list of available reports and the parameters needed to run each one.  None of this is known at compile time and the report definitions can even change with the web portal needing to be recompiled.

I can have a variable number and type of input parameters.

Comment: What do all your classes look like for your parameter model?

Comment: @ErikPhilips the second code block shows the prompt/parameter view model classes.  Though as I review this whole question, I seem to evolved my code away from this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the custom binder. You can simply pass back your view model to the post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessForm(InputParameters viewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

The default MVC binder will match up the form values with the properties of the InputParameters argument. You may need to use a [Bind] attribute on that argument to indicate a variable name prefix that the binder must look for if your view uses any kind of special form variable names.

Comment: I tried that first.  It throws a "Cannot instantiate an Interface" exception before the Action to process the user input.  I assume this is because it cannot determine which child object to instantiate (TextPrompt or MultiSelectPrompt).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect MVC to instantiate an `IInputPrompt` because it has not logic to figure out what class you actually want. Your options are to either create a ModelBinder for model binding to this specific interface, or changing the interface into a concrete class.

Comment: I ended up using reflection in the ModelBinder to determine the type of each class in the collection.